# What are all these shells and which should I keep?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I've inherited a PC and seem to have a bunch of different flavours of powershell. I just need one to do web development but am not sure what the difference between them is. Which should I keep/uninstall?

[image]

Comment: If I'd been given or bought a second hand computer, the very first thing I would do is wipe it & clean install. I wouldn't dream of doing anything else.

Comment: Powershell is installed by default with windows. Just keep it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't uninstall any of them.

The four "Windows PowerShell" entries are distributed as part of Windows 10. The two marked "ISE" provide a minimal script editor-plus-execution-console; the two marked "(x86)" are for a 32-bit environment instead of a 64-bit environment. Microsoft assumes that these PowerShells will be available for administrative tasks, and some of their utility GUIs simply use the GUI to build a PowerShell command and then use PowerShell to execute it. [*ETA: These can't be uninstalled, anyway.*]

The PowerShell 7 entry is for a newer version of PowerShell that is also cross-platform - that is, it is available for Mac and Linux as well as Windows - and supports new features that will not be retrofitted to the Windows PowerShell, and also supports a newer .NET than the Windows PowerShells.

Comment: It's worth pointing out you can't uninstall anyone of them except the PowerShell 7 entry.  PowerShell 5.1 is built-into Windows 10 and cannot actually be removed.

Comment: @Ramhound - A valid point; I suppose I shouldn't assume that "distributed as part of Windows 10" implies "Can't be uninstalled".

Comment: Certainly, The Calculator UWP is distributed and installed by default, but can be removed (with some heartache).

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the info.

Comment: If this answer adequately addressed your concerns, please "Accept" it by clicking the check mark below the voting arrows. This marks the question as resolved, and incidentally throws me a little "rep" on the site.